# How do i execute function after specific time in spring?

Tags: spring, timer, schedule

I want to execute similar source such as the below source in spring.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test() throws Exception{

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("test===========================");
        }
    }, 6000);
    return "test";
}
```

But I don`t know how effective this is. If users connect a lot, it seems to have a lot of problems.
I want more effective how to in spring.
can anyone help me ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you going to do (if you will be more specific: what are you trying to return, why are you using a delayed response?). Also it is not a good idea using another thread into request because every request is a thread himself...
Anyway if you need to schedule, you can try this (you must create this method into a service)

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 6000)
        public StringscheduleFixedDelayTask() {
            return "test";
        }
```

and then use it into your controller:

```
@Autowired
private ServiceName sname;

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test() throws Exception{

  return this.sname.scheduleFixedDelayTask();
}
```

If this is not what are you looking for, please read about @Scheduled annotation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/scheduling.html)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. but I will raise questions more clearly.